# Last bin in histogram has smaller width than others

Tags: d3.js

I have a D3.js histogram graph that has an issue where my last x-axis bin is significantly smaller than than the rest of the bins which are equal width. At first I thought this was a axis issue, but the axis is set with the typical width and height range and domains, making me believe it has to do with my bar code, but I'm not sure what would create just one wrong width for a bing, while the other bins are equal width. Provided below is my code. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
    #sleep-dist-histo {
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke: goldenrod;
    }
</style>

<script>

    var data = [
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "7.01" },
        { "x": "8.39" },
        { "x": "8.22" },
        { "x": "8.31" },
        { "x": "8.33" },
        { "x": "8.16" },
        { "x": "8.00" },
        { "x": "6.04" },
        { "x": "8.18" },
        { "x": "7.47" },
        { "x": "7.57" },
        { "x": "7.11" },
        { "x": "6.59" },
        { "x": "7.51" },
        { "x": "6.31" },
        { "x": "8.01" },
        { "x": "8.14" },
        { "x": "8.26" },
        { "x": "7.44" },
        { "x": "7.54" },
        { "x": "6.23" },
        { "x": "6.25" },
        { "x": "7.50" },
        { "x": "7.45" },
        { "x": "9.34" },
        { "x": "7.53" },
        { "x": "7.11" },
        { "x": "8.17" },
        { "x": "8.02" },
        { "x": "8.12" },
        { "x": "8.14" },
        { "x": "7.49" },
        { "x": "6.35" },
        { "x": "7.07" },
        { "x": "5.46" },
        { "x": "6.56" },
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "8.06" },
        { "x": "7.31" },
        { "x": "8.53" },
        { "x": "7.42" },
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "7.57" },
        { "x": "7.38" },
        { "x": "8.04" },
        { "x": "6.29" },
        { "x": "7.52" },
        { "x": "7.42" },
        { "x": "8.06" },
        { "x": "8.09" },
        { "x": "8.03" },
        { "x": "7.06" },
        { "x": "7.33" },
        { "x": "8.09" },
        { "x": "7.47" },
        { "x": "7.54" },
        { "x": "7.31" },
        { "x": "7.30" },
        { "x": "7.50" },
        { "x": "4.07" },
        { "x": "8.22" },
        { "x": "7.44" }
    ]



    // console.log(data)
    var margin = { top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 60  }
    var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // translate(margin left, margin top)

    // Append x-scale and x-scale tick labels
    var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")");

    // Set x-scale range
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width]);

    // Append x-scale title
    svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Time Asleep in Hours (Bins)");
    
    // Set y-scale range
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, margin.top]);
    
    // Append y-scale
    var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis");
    
    // Append y-scale title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Count of Days Asleep");

    d3.interval(function(){
        update(data)
    }, 1000);

    update(data);

    function update(data){

        // X and Y axis domains
        x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.x })])
        
        var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);
        var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y);

        xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall);
        yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

        var histogram = d3.histogram()
            .value(function(d) { return d.x })
            .domain(x.domain())
            .thresholds(x.ticks());

        var bins = histogram(data);

        y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d){ return d.length; })]);

        // Append bars
        svg.selectAll("bar")
            .data(bins)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 1)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; })
                .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) - 1 ; })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); })
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("id", "sleep-dist-histo");
                
        svg.selectAll("label")
            .data(bins)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
                .text(function(d){ return d.length })
                .attr("x", function(d){ return (x(d.x0) + x(d.x1)) / 2; })
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.length) - 15; })
                .attr("class", "label")
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                // .style("text-anchor", "end")
                ;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the domain of x is [0, 9.34], so it ended up with 9.34 instead of 10 (to keep the same width)

Solution:

1. add `.nice()` to `x` to "Extends the domain so that it starts and ends on nice round values. " (See [Here](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice));
2. remove the last element of the new `bin` data otherwise there will be a zero from 10 to 11

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
    #sleep-dist-histo {
        stroke-width: 0.5;
        stroke: goldenrod;
    }
</style>

<script>

    var data = [
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "7.01" },
        { "x": "8.39" },
        { "x": "8.22" },
        { "x": "8.31" },
        { "x": "8.33" },
        { "x": "8.16" },
        { "x": "8.00" },
        { "x": "6.04" },
        { "x": "8.18" },
        { "x": "7.47" },
        { "x": "7.57" },
        { "x": "7.11" },
        { "x": "6.59" },
        { "x": "7.51" },
        { "x": "6.31" },
        { "x": "8.01" },
        { "x": "8.14" },
        { "x": "8.26" },
        { "x": "7.44" },
        { "x": "7.54" },
        { "x": "6.23" },
        { "x": "6.25" },
        { "x": "7.50" },
        { "x": "7.45" },
        { "x": "9.34" },
        { "x": "7.53" },
        { "x": "7.11" },
        { "x": "8.17" },
        { "x": "8.02" },
        { "x": "8.12" },
        { "x": "8.14" },
        { "x": "7.49" },
        { "x": "6.35" },
        { "x": "7.07" },
        { "x": "5.46" },
        { "x": "6.56" },
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "8.06" },
        { "x": "7.31" },
        { "x": "8.53" },
        { "x": "7.42" },
        { "x": "7.41" },
        { "x": "7.57" },
        { "x": "7.38" },
        { "x": "8.04" },
        { "x": "6.29" },
        { "x": "7.52" },
        { "x": "7.42" },
        { "x": "8.06" },
        { "x": "8.09" },
        { "x": "8.03" },
        { "x": "7.06" },
        { "x": "7.33" },
        { "x": "8.09" },
        { "x": "7.47" },
        { "x": "7.54" },
        { "x": "7.31" },
        { "x": "7.30" },
        { "x": "7.50" },
        { "x": "4.07" },
        { "x": "8.22" },
        { "x": "7.44" }
    ]



    // console.log(data)
    var margin = { top: 15, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 60  }
    var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // translate(margin left, margin top)

    // Append x-scale and x-scale tick labels
    var xAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + height + ")");

    // Set x-scale range
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width]);

    // Append x-scale title
    svg.append("text")             
        .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Time Asleep in Hours (Bins)");
    
    // Set y-scale range
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, margin.top]);
    
    // Append y-scale
    var yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y-axis");
    
    // Append y-scale title
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
        .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
        .attr("dy", "1em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Count of Days Asleep");

   /*  d3.interval(function(){
        update(data)
    }, 1000);
     */
    update(data);

    function update(data){

        // X and Y axis domains
        x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return (+d.x) })]).nice()
        
        var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(x);
        var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(y);

        xAxisGroup.call(xAxisCall);
        yAxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);

        var histogram = d3.histogram()
            .value(function(d) { return +d.x })
            .domain(x.domain())
            .thresholds(x.ticks());

        var bins = histogram(data);

        y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d){ return d.length; })]);
  bins = bins.slice(0, bins.length-1)
        // Append bars
        svg.selectAll("bar")
            .data(bins)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 1)
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; })
                .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) - 1 ; })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); })
                .style("fill", "steelblue")
                .attr("id", "sleep-dist-histo");
                
        svg.selectAll("label")
            .data(bins)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
                .text(function(d){ return d.length })
                .attr("x", function(d){ return (x(d.x0) + x(d.x1)) / 2; })
                .attr("y", function(d){ return y(d.length) - 15; })
                .attr("class", "label")
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                // .style("text-anchor", "end")
                ;
    }
</script>
```